# $.ajax working with file and not url?

Tags: html, ajax, json, append

in the $.ajax function the url part has data.json which is a text file but i want to put a url i.e.

the code works with

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#content').html('');
    $.ajax({
            url:'data.json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                    $('#content').append('<p>'+data.rank+'</p>');
            }
    });});
```

where data.json is a text file...but wen i replace 'data.json' with 
'http://twittercounter.com/api/username=Anand_Dasgupta&output=json&results=3'...which is the actual url ,then there is no output...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#content').html('');
    $.ajax({
          url:'http://twittercounter.com/api/username=Anand_Dasgupta&output=json&results=3',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                    $('#content').append('<p>'+data.rank+'</p>');
            }
    });});
```

an advice will be highly appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @harshath.jr correctly pointed out, you will need to proxy that request through your domain, for example:

```
  $('#content').html('');
    $.ajax({
          url:'twitterProxy.php?username=Anand_Dasgupta&results=3',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                    $('#content').append('<p>'+data.rank+'</p>');
            }
    });});
```

Comment: I agree that a proxy is needed, but the one suggested above could be quite dangerous as it effectively voids the cross domain rules. The example above appears to allude to a proxy designed to accept any url thrown at it. This would allow potential attackers to run foreign code in the context of your site.

I'd suggest writing a proxy specifically for the services you require, something like "TwitterCounter.aspx?username=Anand_Dasgupta&results=3". Such a proxy could be refined to make assumptions on the results you require, i.e. you may only either want to return JSON.

Comment: @kim3er - absolutely, I threw in the above example to better illustrate what it means to proxy the request, I will edit the answer to reflect the better-practice you have suggested.

Comment: dont think its cross domain problem...the url just gives me back a json file..if u put the url in ur web browsr ul get 1 too..wat i could do is call the url using $.ajax and store it in text file and then call another ajax to use the txt file again... like 
store the json response that i get from
http://twittercounter.com/api/username=Anand_Dasgupta&output=json&results=3
and put in in data.json n call data.json again...

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a case of cross domain ajax prevention.

You will need to use a server side proxy script for this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have typo in url, the question mark is significant since it differentiate url from parameters:

```
http://twittercounter.com/api/?username=Anand_Dasgupta&output=json&results=3
```

As for me looks like missing some more parameters.

EDIT:

The below answers looks more correct than mine, it definitely could be cross domain access.

Answer (score 1):

using [$.getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) should solve all your worries. And it'll call you in the morning.